# Site migration linux->local wamp, Apache error log displays weirdest paths

Tags: php, apache, path, wamp

First, an excerpt from the error:

```
[Sun Feb 22 19:17:56.601528 2015] [:error] [pid 16408:tid 1528] [client ::1:61136] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun Feb 22 19:17:56.601528 2015] [:error] [pid 16408:tid 1528] [client ::1:61136] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html\\index.php:0
[Sun Feb 22 19:17:56.601528 2015] [:error] [pid 16408:tid 1528] [client ::1:61136] PHP   2. include() C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html\\index.php:12
[Sun Feb 22 19:17:56.602528 2015] [:error] [pid 16408:tid 1528] [client ::1:61136] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'phpMail.php' for inclusion
(include_path='.;C:\\php\\pear
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/lib/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/admin/lib/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/b2evo_captcha_fonts/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/b2evo_captcha_tmp/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/fonts/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/html/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/krumo/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/krumo/docs/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/krumo/docs/Krumo/
:C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html/stdlib/k 
in C:\\wamp\\www\\thesite\\domains\\thesite\\public_html\\config.php on line 152
```

And from autoconf.php, seemingly path-related...

```
    $path = realpath("./").'/';
if (preg_match("/(.*)\/admin\//", $path, $path1)) {
   $path = $path1[1].'/';
}
$CFG["path"]["www"] = $path.'\\';
$url_www = '/';
if (preg_match("/.*\/public_html\/(.*)\//", $path, $matches)) {
   if (preg_match("/^\/{$matches[1]}\/*/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $kk)) {
      $url_www = '/'.$matches[1].'/';
   }
}
$CFG["url"]["www"] = $url_www;


$CFG["theme"] = "thesite";
```

And finally, config.php, opening lines:

```
require_once("autoconf.php");
// path (with trailing slashes)
$CFG["path"]["admin"] = $CFG["path"]["www"] . "admin/";
$CFG["path"]["ext"] = $CFG["path"]["www"] . "ext/";
$CFG["path"]["public"] = $CFG["path"]["www"] . "public/";
$CFG["path"]["js"] = $CFG["path"]["ext"] . "js/";
$CFG["path"]["font"] = $CFG["path"]["ext"] . "font/";
$CFG["path"]["files"] = $CFG["path"]["public"] . "files/";
// url (with trailing slashes)
$CFG["url"]["admin"] = $CFG["url"]["www"] . "admin/";
$CFG["url"]["ext"] = $CFG["url"]["www"] . "ext/";
$CFG["url"]["public"] = $CFG["url"]["www"] . "public/";
$CFG["url"]["js"] = $CFG["url"]["ext"] . "js/";
$CFG["url"]["font"] = $CFG["url"]["ext"] . "font/";
$CFG["url"]["files"] = $CFG["url"]["public"] . "files/";
$CFG["url"]["css"] = $CFG['url']['www'].'theme/'.$CFG['theme'].'/css/';

// lib path (with trailing slashes)
$CFG["path"]["lib"] = array(
    $CFG["path"]["www"] . "stdlib/",
    $CFG["path"]["www"] . "lib/",
    $CFG["path"]["admin"] . "lib/"
);

// libraries (don't touch)
//////////////////////////////////////

// add our lib path's to php include path
setLibPath($CFG["path"]["lib"]);

//captcha
include("phpMail.php");
```

Well, basically the log has error for each library that is included via

> include()

to config.php

So far I get vertigo from looking at all that stuff in configuration files, being not the biggest PHP ace me.

But I do feel that I'm overlooking something extremely simple somewhere in there, to do with paths and how they're constructed.

And boy, do all these backslashes make me sick...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `include_path` in php.ini (phpForApache.ini) has got `:` colon seperators between folders and thats UNIX speak.

I guess you followed a setup tutorial that was aimed at UNIX and not Windows.

Change the `include_path` to use semi colons `;` as seperators like so and remove the non existant folders at the same time eg `C:/php/pear`

```
include_path=".;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/lib/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/admin/lib/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/b2evo_captcha_fonts/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/b2evo_captcha/b2evo_captcha_tmp/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/fonts/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/html/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/krumo/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/krumo/docs/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/krumo/docs/Krumo/
;C:\wamp\www\thesite\domains\thesite\public_html/stdlib/k
```